# How to get cpu cores utilizations in xen?

Tags: xen

I have installed `xen` as hypervisor and there are `dom0` and some paravirtualized machins as `domu` VMs on it.
I know `xentop` is used for checking the performance of system and virtual machines, But, it just gives the total usage of cpus!
**So, is there any tool or any way to get cpu usages per cores?**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mpstat` tool from the `sysstat` package.

By issuing the command `mpstat -P 0,1 1` you can track the utilization of CPUs 0 and 1 on a 1 second interval.

See `man mpstat` for further details and possible options.

Comment: In a virtual machine, it just gives the `vcpu` utilizations of virtual machine, not physical cpu utilization.

Comment: Who said that you should run `mpstat` within a virtual machine?

Comment: After installing xen hypervisor, There is a `dom0` virtual machine with privilege to control other guest virtual machine named `domU` : http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide

Comment: I'm just trying to help you but I sense that you do not appreciate it much. In my lab I allow the control domain to use every (v)CPU and therefore the `mpstat` tool can read the information of all the installed CPUs. Now I'm testing (stressing) the CPU in a test domain I see different readings compared to the control domain on the same CPU. Did you have had the chance to look at the tools `xenperf` and `cpuperf-xen`. They unfortunately do not work in my environment yet...

Comment: I really appreciate any help but I thought you misunderstood the question, the utilization must be measured through the hypervisor not the OSs. Right now I'm looking for `xenperf`. I will inform you about the results. do you have link to installation and usage of xenperf in ubuntu?

Comment: I understand, thanks for your clarification :-). From what I've read is that in order to use `xenperf` the performance counters must be compiled with xen. I'm not sure if the Ubuntu package of xen has the performance counters compiled, the Debian version 4.1 apparently not.